# Arduino Serial Output Dropping Characters

Tags: serial-port, arduino

I have a bizarre one here with the serial output when trying to write some code for my Arduino Uno.

I have this proto-code:

```
MyClass myclass;

void setup()
{
   Serial.Begin(9600);
   Serial.println("Starting...");
}

void loop()
{
   int status = myclass.DoWork();
   Serial.println("Status: " + status);
}

class MyClass 
{
   int DoWork()
   {
      Serial.println("Doing some work...");
      return 1;
   }
}
```

Now when this runs I get the following output:

Starting...

Doing some work...

atus: 1

So the strange part is the "Status: 1" missing the first few characters. Is this because I am using serial in an object improperly or something?

I have noticed when I reference another library that also uses serial like MyClass does that I get other strange output behavior... so I assume that I am doing something wrong.

**EDIT:** In the end this turned out to actually be a memory issue. A library I was including was quite large and it was consuming the available memory. I found this by adding a few more debugging statements and found the corruption shifted around based on the string lengths and positions. By using the F() function I moved the strings to flash memory (e.g. I now run  Serial.println(F("Starting..."));  and it has corrected the strange output.

Comment: It is *very* unlikely that characters get dropped when you send.  Far more likely is that the receiver drops them.  We can't see it.

Comment: Could it be that you are overflowing the Serial buffer? Try to do a delay(5) in the loop() and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I think you should remove your "EDIT" comment, and make it an answer that you "auto-accept". SO is not only for solving *your* problem, but also giving hints for other people who might run into your problem one day or the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end this turned out to actually be a memory issue. A library I was including was quite large and it was consuming the available memory. I found this by adding a few more debugging statements and found the corruption shifted around based on the string lengths and positions. By using the F() function I moved the strings to flash memory (e.g. I now run Serial.println(F("Starting...")); and it has corrected the strange output.

Comment: This is actually incorrect.  While using the F() macro will have solved your problem, the reason is not because of memory issues, but for the type-conversion issues highlighted by @jdr5ca above.  `"abcdef"` has type `const char *`.  The result of adding an integer to `const char *` is to move the pointer, essentially dropping characters from your string.  `"abcdef" + 2 == "cdef"`. `F("abcdef")` has type `const __FlashStringHelper *`, i.e. it is a different type.

Comment: Hey @GotWoods, I found your question because I've been experiencing this same issue. I was using typecasting `print("intValue: " + (String)theInt)` which worked for a while but fell apart tonight (not sure why). I refactored all my `Serial` activity to follow @jdr5ca's answer and that worked like a charm.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot add strings and integers in C++.  It would have been better for you if this failed to compile:

```
Serial.println("Status: " + status);
```

Instead the compiler guessed at something.  It guessed wrong.  Use this:

```
Serial.print("Status :");
Serial.println(status);
```

or for complete control of outputting numbers and strings learn to use C string formatting, **sprintf()**

Comment: or the OP can use `strncpy()`

Comment: strncpy() will just copy strings.  It won't automatically format an int to a char[]

Comment: I'm no expert, but my reading of the ARDUINO string class (not the C++ class) indicates that the "Status: " + status expression would auto convert the int to a string, and then creaate a new string that is the combination of the "Status" string and the new string.    That said, I prefer breaking it up into print/println as you did -- the auto-convert and new String object seems like it will hit the heap in a way that will cause trouble down the line.

Comment: That may have happened, except "Status :" is not a String, it is a C char[].  If the code was println(String("Status :") + String(status)), then the conversion and concat would have worked.  If the code was println(String("Status :") + status) you might have hoped the compiler would guessed what to do.  The function println(String s) does not exist.  So the compiler has to find a matching function and conversions to get to char[].  What would it do, convert the int to a String, perform the add, and cast the sum to a char[]?  Or would it cast the String to a char[], and perform the add?

Comment: As I stated it was proto-code. I believe that bobwki is correct though as the documents I have read state that you can add them.

Comment: This answer is likely true, but I don't think it impacts the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One more possible explanation.

I was running minicom to monitor, and I usually like that it auto-reconnects after resetting my device.

Well I minimized a terminal running minicom last night, and today I started a new instance that somehow also got connected to the same serial port (if that is even possible).

I think the two instances of minicom were each reading ~50% of the serial characters roughly at random, leaving me with quite a mess of text.