# Serial communication from an arduino to python without dropping characters

Tags: python, arduino

I have an arduino I am using to gather data from a sensor and send the data to a python program. Unfortunately, during the transfer, some characters are lost about 5% of the time. For my application, I will ultimately be collecting points about every 100ms (or better, if I can manage it), and I need 99.5%+ data integrity. I'd originally hoped to be able to do the data processing as the data are received, but this seemed to make the data loss worse.

I have the arduino code set to send a string with the data in it beginning with 'a' and ending with 'b', with a comma and a space between each data field.

Because it was dropping characters, I initially tried sending the data twice and writing python code to fix between the repeated lines, but this still gave problems in around 1% of data points.

What I am currently trying is having python tell the arduino how many characters are between 'a' and 'b'. The arduino waits until it receives the correct number then moves on through the delay and back through the data acquisition.

On the python side, I am currently trying to receive the code, calculate the string length between 'a' and 'b', send the string length to the arduino, and move on when it gets the expected length. It sometimes works, but not always. (For reasons that don't seem to matter, I am using a user-entered 'z' as a line ending because the arduino doesn't seem to be reading '\n' properly).

**Stripped down Arduino code**

```cpp
void loop() {
  outputString = makeOutput(); //code to make the output string
  int outlen = outputString.length();
  int diff = 1;
  while (diff != 0) {
    Serial.println(outputString);
    inputString = "";
    stringComplete = false;
    while (!stringComplete) {
      selectPort();
    } //reads the data from the port
    diff = outlen - inputString.substring(0, 2).toInt();
  }
  CorrectedDelay(); //runs the delay based on the actual time difference
}
```

**Stripped down Python code:**

```
import serial
import sys
import time

def read_data(self):
    count = 0
    temp = self.data_queue
    tempa = temp.find("a")
    tempb = temp.find("b", tempa)
    if tempb-tempa>10:
        sendstr = str(tempb-tempa+1)+"z"
    else:
        sendstr = "10z"
    while True:
        count+=1
        if count>10000: return "Count Error"

        self.port.write(sendstr)

        self.data_queue =  self.port.read_all()

        temp = self.data_queue
        tempa = temp.find("a")
        tempb = temp.find("b", tempa)
        if tempb-tempa>10:
            sendstr = str(tempb-tempa+1)+"z"
        else:
            sendstr = "10z"
        if sendstr == "17z":
            time.sleep(1.0/1000.0)
            self.port.reset_input_buffer()

            return temp[tempa:tempb+1]
```

If I set up port2 as the class this is in (currently it just has some initialisation stuff and a function choosing and opening the port), it will sometimes output the correct string and sometimes not:

Running `port.read_data()` gives output (3 examples) such as:
'a, +0048604832, b'
'b'
'a, +0074239532, b'

The first and third are right, the 'b' isn't.

If I just run a loop as:
    for a in range(20):
      temp.append(port.read_data())
A sample output of temp is:

['a, +0011015216, b', 'a, +0059960728, b', 'a, +0069954852, b', 'a, +0069954852, b', 'a, +0069954852, b', 'a, +0069954852, b', 'a, +0069954852, b', 'a, +0069954852, b', 'a, +0069954852, b', 'a, +0069954852, b', 'a, +0069954852, b', 'a, +0079949280, b', 'a, +0079949280, b', 'a, +0079949280, b', 'a, +0079949280, b', 'a, +0079949280, b', 'a, +0079949280, b', 'a, +0079949280, b', 'a, +0079949280, b', 'a, +0079949280, b']

(i.e. the first 3 are right, the next 8 just repeat the 3rd, the next one is right, and the rest repeat that one).

I have tried approaches with Arduino IDE serial monitor open and closed. I have tried running from command-line and from an SPE shell. I am running within Ubuntu in Virtual Box on a sparkfun redboard using the Arduino Uno setting.

**Update**

Further testing (with a 1 second delay in the arduino) over 1000 points gave only 20 instances where the value was received only once. Besides those, the smallest number of points being repeated was 3 repeats while the largest instance being repeated 47 times. There were 28 instances of the correct 1s time gap (or close to). 21 instances with about a 2s gap, 2 with a 3s gap and 8 with a 7s gap. Each of the larger gaps seems corresponds a larger number of repeated points.

Comment: Have you tried simply printing out all the characters as you receive them from the serial object?  That would allow you to tell the difference between a serial communication problem and a coding problem.  In any case you've left out some important pieces of code.  It looks like `read_all` gets the characters from the serial port.  That's the functionality that's not working but you didn't present that function.  How does the Python serial code know when the transmission from the Arduino is finished?  Does it wait for a delimiter character?  Is there a timeout?

Comment: `read_all` is from the serial library. I've tried with `read`, `readline` and `readlines`. None of them seem to make any particular difference.

Comment: `self.port` is an instance of the serial port. Besides that, printing out the characters as I receive them is how I started. I then moved on to doing `readlines(500)` while sending the lines from the arduino twice. I still had the issue of characters being dropped which is why I am trying the current implementation, which shouldn't give results with missing data, but is having the issues outlined above.

Comment: @PaulCornelius, to answer your other questions, the python code doesn't know - if I've coded correctly (which I obviously haven't!) if just reads everything that is there, and when it is happy it clears the input buffer. That's what I am trying to do with `self.port.reset_input_buffer()`. I don't seem to have been having problems with it reading less than an entire line. The problems have more been that what should be 'a, 12345, b' being read as 'a, 1245, b'

Comment: This is confusing to me.  In your post you describe a situation where almost the entire message (except the last character) is missing, or a whole message gets repeated for no apparent reason.  Now you say that individual characters within a message are randomly dropped at the lowest level?  If that's really the case, you've got some other basic issue.  There is no way you can fool around with Python code to suddenly bring back those characters if they were never there in the first place.

Comment: `read_all` is not documented in PySerial.  Why don't you use one of the other read functions?

Comment: @PaulCornelius just to make my life more difficult, as I dropped the delay on the arduino below 1s, `readline` started working pretty well! I don't understand it, but I'll go with it. (Still not perfectly, but not terrible). To try to clarify from your other question, my underlying issue **is** that individual characters are dropped. Everything else is workaround. That the workaround introduces new errors and issues is neither surprising nor desirable, but is where I am up to.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense to me.  My company makes instruments that communicate with a host PC by RS232.  The failure rate is less than one part per billion - I can't even measure it.  If we had the level of problems you describe we'd be out of business.  It's suspicious that you *shorten* a time delay and suddenly the failure rate drops.  If I were you, I'd write a simple program that just sends messages ("Hello" followed by a number, for example) and gets a correct reply to each one.  The success rate should be 100%.  Then I would build my data acquisition program on top of that.

Comment: @Paul, thank you for your time and help. Your suggestion is more-or-less what I did when I first started noticing the problem. (That's why I started using 'a' and 'b' as start and end marks) - I did it with the time stamp as the number. Typically, over 10k lines, I will get periods of 1-2k without any dropped characters and periods of 1-2k with enough dropped characters to be a problem. Without error checking, I've never got 100% over 10k data points. And no, it doesn't make sense to me either.

Comment: One more thought.  If the Arduino or the host computer's serial port is really so unreliable, somebody would have reported it by now.  These things are sold by the thousands.  Have you checked out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853683/arduino-serial-erratic-behaviour-missing-characters-and-occasionally-the-whole-t or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256875/arduino-serial-output-dropping-characters or https://forums.electricimp.com/discussion/2510/serial-from-arduino-to-imp-loses-characters.  In every case it turned out not to be the device itself but how it was used.

Comment: I'm fully prepared to believe that the environment is the issue (as in the first example). Thanks to your help, luck and the many sites I have been checking, it seems to be working pretty well - I'm typically getting one point with a delay significantly more than expected about every 20k-60k points. I can handle that for my application.